# Are there any cross platform Java packages that can play, seek, and pitch shift MP3, WAV, OGG, MOD, S3M, IT, XM, and MIDI?

Tags: java, audio, cross-platform

Or if not all of those, at least MP3, WAV, OGG, and MIDI, and preferably noarch (works on 32 bit and 64 bit builds) I tried using Audiere's Java bindings, but they are 32 bit, and it would be a pain to have to compile it in all builds and platforms (plus I'm not familiar with compiling)

Answer (score 1):

Try [JavaZoom](http://www.javazoom.net/). With them you can handle MP3 and OGG files. I thought Java by default should be able to handle WAV file (as they are not compressed in any way), but I'm not sure since I've never used Java to play WAV files (only MP3 files). Not certain about MIDI though.

There's also the JMF (Java Media Framework), but that requires you to install the framework on client computers before you can use it's features. With JavaZoom, all you need to do is to include their jars in your project. I've been looking high and low for alternative projects which deals with playback of MP3 files, but it seems like JavaZoom and JMF are the only decent alternatives out there.